# List Comprehension to JSON in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have a python list of objects which looks like so

```
[
<NodeImage: id=aki-00501552, name=ubuntu/kernels-testing/ubuntu-lucid-amd64-linux-image-2.6.32-341-ec2-v-2.6.32-341.42-kernel, driver=Amazon EC2 (ap-southeast-1)  ...>, 
<NodeImage: id=aki-00c4bd52, name=ubuntu-kernels/ubuntu-lucid-amd64-linux-image-2.6.32-316-ec2-v-2.6.32-316.31-kernel, driver=Amazon EC2 (ap-southeast-1)  ...>, 
<NodeImage: id=aki-015d1253, name=RH-pv-grub-hd00-V1.01-x86_64, driver=Amazon EC2 (ap-southeast-1)  ...>, <NodeImage: id=aki-01f58a53, name=None, driver=Amazon EC2 (ap-southeast-1)  ...>
]
```

I want to convert this to JSON format which will look like so,

```
[
 {
   "id":"aki-00501552", "name":"ubuntu/kernels-testing/ubuntu-lucid-amd64-linux-image-2.6.32-341-ec2-v-2.6.32-341.42-kernel","driver":"Amazon EC2 (ap-southeast-1)"
 },
 {
   "id":"aki-00c4bd52", "name":"ubuntu-kernels/ubuntu-lucid-amd64-linux-image-2.6.32-316-ec2-v-2.6.32-316.31-kernel", "driver":"Amazon EC2 (ap-southeast-1)"
 },
 {
   "id":"aki-015d1253", "name":"RH-pv-grub-hd00-V1.01-x86_64", "driver":"Amazon EC2 (ap-southeast-1)"
 }
]
```

Is there a way to do this conversion.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Yes, the way is to write some code.

Comment: write a custom encoder (serializer), and pass it `json.dumps([...], default=your_custom_encoder)`

Comment: What is the type of your objects? This information is necessary so that we know how to get to the information they contain.

Comment: @KevinGuan  I don't want you to write a program for me. I have tried different approaches and nothing has worked out. As I am new to python I just wanted to know if there is something which I don't know or missed out.

Comment: @shwetha *I have tried different approaches.* Great, but why don't add at least one of them into your question?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is just an array of objects containing strings/numbers and other json-compatible values you can just use:

```
s = json.dumps([x.__dict__ for x in data])
```

In Python `x.__dict__` is a dictionary that contains all data members of object `x`.

Comment: `x.__dict__` is customarily obtained with a built-in function: `vars(x)`.

Comment: @EOL: "customarily" looks like a bit strong... in my experience `__dict__` is much more common